# TypeError at /register/ 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

This method I am Calling Weather API with data and the parameter in the form of a dictionary, but its throwing error in line:

```
email=form.cleaned_data.get['email']

TypeError: 'dict' object is not Callable
```

My code:

```
def register(request):
headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json','PRIVATE-TOKEN': '******',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer *******',
    'Authorization': 'Basic *******'}

form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST':
  
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        email=form.cleaned_data.get['email']
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password =form.cleaned_data.get['password']
        
        data={"username":username,"email":email,"password":password} 
        response = requests.post('http://172.16.0.111/api/v4/users/', headers=headers, data=data)     
        response.json()
        messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
        return redirect('login')
else:
    form = UserRegisterForm()
return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

`.get()` is a method of dict, while directly accessing key you could use brackets `[]`

```
email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')

# or 
email = form.cleaned_data['email']
```

Comment: I corrected it thanks , but I received another error message                         
      JSONDecodeError at /register/
      Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @gmizaamel  same error for `password =form.cleaned_data.get['password']`

Comment: @gmizaamel `JSONDecodeError` is due to these lines `requests.post() and response.json()`, read more about the `requests` docs on how to login user